# Program with Perl's Term::Animation quits prematurely

Tags: perl, curses

When trying to move the object by pressing `"d"` or `"a"` perl quits.
I thought the problem was related to using the `quit()` function which was not defined. To fix this, I tried using the `endwin()` function from the `Curses` library to end the program correctly.

```
if ($in eq 'q') {
    endwin(); # Terminate program execution correctly
    last;
}
```

More kept coming out

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Curses;
use Term::Animation;

my $anim = Term::Animation->new();
# Set the starting position of the object
my $x = 0;

$anim->new_entity(
    shape           => ['@'],  # Symbol of the object
    position        => [$x, 0, 0],
    auto_trans      => 1,
);

halfdelay(1);

while (1) {
    my $in = lc(getch());

    if ($in eq 'q') {
        quit();  # exit
    }
    elsif ($in eq 'r') {
        last;  # Redraw (will recreate all objects)
    }
    elsif ($in eq 'p') {
        $anim->pause(!$anim->paused());  # Pause or resume the animation
    }
    elsif ($in eq 'd' || $in eq KEY_RIGHT) {
       # Move right (increment x position)
        $x++;
        $anim->set_entity_position(0, $x, 0, 0);
    }
    elsif ($in eq 'a' || $in eq KEY_LEFT) {
        # Mover para a esquerda (decrementar a posição x)
        $x--;
        $anim->set_entity_position(0, $x, 0, 0);
    }

    $anim->animate();  # Update the animation
}

$anim->update_term_size();
$anim->remove_all_entities();
```

Comment: Perl has an [`exit`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#exit) function. Is that what you mean instead of `quit()`?

Comment: I mean that when the ```"d"``` key is pressed instead of moving the object incrementing to the right, it happens that the execution (interpetration) ends, and the screen exits.

Answer (score 1):

It's being hidden but the program is dying with the error

> Can't locate object method "set_entity_position" via package "Term::Animation"

And indeed, I see no such method in the [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::Animation).

[Term::Animation::Entity](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::Animation::Entity) have a `position` method which can be used to change their position. Of course, you will need to obtain the entity you want to move first. `->new_entity` returns a reference to the entity is creates.

---

Regarding `quit()`, you should be using

```perl
$anim->end();
```

to set the screen back to normal, followed by

```perl
last;        # Exit loop (which exits the program)
```

or

```perl
exit;         # Exit the program directly.
```

This suggests the `r` key doesn't do what you expect it to do.